# Parrot OS, VirtualBox, doesn't persist new files/folders made on desktop

Tags: virtualbox, parrotsec

I download the newest version of parrot os and add the iso file to a new virtual machine. It boots fine. When it loads I choose "try/install" and it continues to the desktop. Then I click the "Install Parrot" file on desktop and it installs with no errors, and then I reboot via the prechecked "reboot now" option after install.

When I reboot the options are still "try/install" as if I haven't installed it and the "Install Parrot" file is still on the desktop.  Then I create a folder on the desktop, but when I send a shutdown signal and restart the machine the new folder is gone.  Any idea why this is happening? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess your VM keeps booting off the installer. Change the boot order / eject installer iso.

Answer (score 1):

1- Power off your virtual machine
2- Go to setting>system
3- you can see boot order option there
4- click on Hard Disk and take it to first position by clicking the right arrow up.
Now just click ok and start your machine it will make file on directory